# Buffered text writer to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, file-io

So I am trying to return a large string array of length 200, but the code I am using only returns 15/ sets the array length to 15 during execution when it has been initiated to reserve 200 spaces as the size of the array may change so I made it big to try and accommodate different sizes.

```
public static String[] populateArray(String fileName)
{
    String [] record = new String [200]; // array length is 200
    try
    {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line = null;
    int counter = 0;
    int arrayLength = 0; // using this to check length during execution
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null && counter < 200)
    {
     record[counter] = line;   
     counter +=1; 
     arrayLength = record[0].length(); // the file contains 20 lines to input here but
                                                                           only does 15
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {
       System.out.println("There was an error while trying to access the  file");
    }
   return record; 
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `arrayLength = record[0].length()` inside the loop? `record[0]` is assigned in the first iteration and is never updated after that, so you can move that line outside the loop. Or you can do something else, because I can't seem to find any reason why `arrayLength` would have anything to do with the length of the first line of input. *<confused>*

Answer (score 2):

Is the first line of the file 15 characters long? It looks like you're finding the length of that string, instead of the amount of lines read in. Furthermore, you set the arrayLength variable to the same value, in each loop iteration.

If you want to count lines read, I suggest just printing the counter variable.

The code you posted seems to work, reading in all the file's lines (With my test file). I'm guessing, therefore, that your issue was with looking at the wrong variable in order to verify what was read in.

Comment: P.s. If you want the array to match the amount of lines in your file, I recommend having a countLines(String filename) method like this: 

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
        lineCount++;
    }

Which returns lineCount. Then initialise your array like so: 

    record = new String[countLines("test.txt")];